# How to put contains on DataTable Rows using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This works:

```
 exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<int>("GENARTNR").Equals(int.Parse(nodeID))).Count() > 0;
```

Now `nodeID` is a string which can have more than 1 nodeIdz so `100,178,111,200 or 100 or 200,100`

Now I want to do something like:

```
  exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(nodeID.Contains(c => c.Field<string>("GENARTNR")));
```

But I am getting :

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'char' because it is not a delegate type
```

Any work around this or some other suggestion?

Comment: Add to end of Linq : .CopyToDataTable() : dt.AsEnumerable().Where(nodeID.Contains(c => c.Field<string>("GENARTNR"))).CopyToDataTable()

Comment: @jdweng: Why? He doesn't want a `DataTable` but a `bool`

Comment: Then use : if(exists.Count() > 0){......} which doesn't give an exception when the results is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `Field<string>("GENARTNR")` is it's actually an `int` column.

You can use this approach that uses `Contains` with an `int[]`:

```
int[] nodeIDs = ParseNodeId(nodeId);
exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(r => nodeIDs.Contains(r.Field<int>("GENARTNR")));
```

---

```
private static int[] ParseNodeId(string nodeId)
{
    return nodeId?.Trim().Split(',')
        .Select(n => int.TryParse(n.Trim(), out int id) ? id : (int?)null)
        .Where(x => x.HasValue)
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<int>();
}
```

Comment: Getting error:
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32'.
on :
exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(r => bgnrIDs.Contains(r.Field<int>("BGNR")));

Comment: Then use `Field<Int16>` or `Field<short>`.